# Access owner members in a nested class

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-2.0, nested, accessor

I have a special label in my form, that should show in a tooltip some text. 
The label is declared as private class in the form (nested control), and should "see" the ToolTip control of the parent form.

Here is the code. Surely, I obtains errors here, because the constructor is called before the private control addition in the owner form control collection...

*Edit:* 
Is there a possibility do not pass the form1 or the toolTip control in constructor?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1() 
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            FormLabel myFormLabel = new FormLabel("uraaaaa!");

            this.Controls.Add(myFormLabel);

            myFormLabel.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        }

        private class FormLabel : Label
        {
            public FormLabel(string toolTip) : base()
            {
                this.Text = toolTip.ToUpperInvariant();

                (this.FindForm() as Form1).toolTip1.SetToolTip(this, toolTip);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you *not* want to pass the right form to the constructor? It's the simplest way of achieving what you want, and doesn't require FindForm/ParentForm to be "ready".

Comment: yes, but this is not a public class, in your case I can pass in the parameter an other instance of the Form1... Finally, I can't deny that your suggestion works, but is not the elegant solution, IMHO.

Comment: @serhio: In what way is it not elegant? It gives the class all the information it needs, rather than relying on the exact timing of initialization etc. It's therefore less brittle and more simple... what's not to like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temporary solution can be like:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(){
            this.InitializeComponent();
            FormLabel myFormLabel = new FormLabel("uraaaaa!");
            this.Controls.Add(myFormLabel);
            myFormLabel.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        }

    private class FormLabel : Label
    {
        private string toolTipText;
        public FormLabel(string toolTip) : base() {                
            this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.toolTipText = toolTip.ToUpperInvariant();
        }

        protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e) {
            Form1 f1 = (this.Parent as Form1);
            if (f1 != null)
                f1.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this, this.toolTipText);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass the form into the constructor of FormLabel?

```
public Form1() 
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    FormLabel myFormLabel = new FormLabel(this, "uraaaaa!");
    this.Controls.Add(myFormLabel);
    myFormLabel.Location = new Point(20, 20);
}

private class FormLabel : Label
{
    public FormLabel(Form1 form, string toolTip) : base()
    {
        this.Text = toolTip.ToUpperInvariant();
        form.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this, toolTip);
    }
}
```

I would expect that to work... if it doesn't, please give details of what errors you're seeing. I'm assuming there's a good reason to do this in real life - it feels a bit convoluted to me at the moment.

Comment: I can pass the toolTip in constructor too but the question is not in passing supplementary parameters in constructor..

Comment: @serhio: as your class is nested, you have access to all the declared members in the containing class.

Comment: @leppie ??? in other words, you say that from FormLabel I can "see" the Form1 members? How?

Comment: @serhio: yes. Get a reference of the form and access it. The compiler wont complain.

Comment: @leppie: "Get a reference of the form". I don't understand. You propose me to pass the reference in constructor?

Comment: @serhio: where ever you want. Point is, if you have Form1 f, you can access the tooltip as f.toolTip1, like you did in your question.

Comment: @serhio: FormLabel has access to the members of an instance of Form1, because it's within the program text of Form1.

Comment: so, I need to **pass** somehow a reference to the form1 to my Label. Is no other way to obtain it?..

Comment: I believe that you can use this.Parent inside your FormLabel class to get a reference to the containing Form (Form inherits from Control)

Comment: @Kragen: Yes, but only after it's been added to the parent control... @serhio: Why are you trying so desperately to avoid the most obvious solution?

Comment: @jon:

I have problems with... because in the constructor I can't set the tooltip. is not added to the controls form yet.

Comment: @serhio: That's going to be a problem however you pass it. Either make the FormLabel add itself to the form, or set the tooltip afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any instance of `ToolTip` to set a tooltip - You may find it easier to create a new instance of `ToolTip`, rather than re-using the one on the Form:

```
public FormLabel(string toolTip) : base()
{
    this.Text = toolTip.ToUpperInvariant();

    ToolTip myToolTip = new ToolTip();
    myToolTip.SetToolTip(this, toolTip);
}
```

Alternatively you could explicitly pass an instance of ToolTip to the control, like this:

```
public Form1() 
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    FormLabel myFormLabel = new FormLabel("uraaaaa!", this.toolTip1);
    this.Controls.Add(myFormLabel);
    myFormLabel.Location = new Point(20, 20);
}

private class FormLabel : Label
{
    public FormLabel(string text, ToolTip toolTip) : base()
    {
        this.Text = text.ToUpperInvariant();
        toolTip.SetToolTip(this, text);
    }
}
```

Does this help clarify things a little?

Comment: toolTip.SetToolTip(this, toolTip); in constructor will not work, because **this** is not yet(at construction time) a control of parent form

Comment: **this** doesn't need to be a parent of the control form in order to set a tooltip.